# "He will come back in two hours" vs. "He will come back after two hours"

Tags: expression-choice

> He will come back in two hours.

vs.

> He will come back after two hours.

What's the subtle diff?

Comment: There isn't any "diff". If the intended sense is that he may return *at any time during the next two hours* (but not later), that would be phrased as *"He will come back **within** two hours"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers there could be a difference if the person hasn't left yet. "He will go in one hour and come back after two hours."

Comment: @FumbleFingers I would argue that the implications do differ, more than subtly.

Comment: @curiousdannii: That just creates an ambiguity that's not relevant to OP's context. Will he return two hours after the time of speaking, or two hours after he leaves? (i.e. - *three* hours after time of speaking).

Comment: @FumbleFingers How do you know what's relevant to the OP's context? They did ask for the subtle diff after all...

Comment: @FumbleFingers the OP didn't supply any context.  If you inferred one, you did it yourself.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're asking the question, but the biggest difference to my ear is that the second phrase was uttered by someone who isn't a native English speaker.  The second phrase sounds unnatural to me; though I've heard non-native English speakers express this idea in this way.

Comment: As a native English speaker, @Dan, I've definitely heard the second option - used by native English speakers.

Comment: @itsbruce in what context?  I suppose you might say it if there was a timed test or something.  "After two hours" used this way means to me that the elapsed time is somehow a requirement; "in two hours" sounds like an estimate of how long it will take.

Comment: I have no idea where you get requirement. Suggest you write your own answer and explain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> He will come back in two hours

This strongly implies that his return will be in two hours from *now* (the point in time at which this statement is made).

> He will come back after two hours

This implies he will return two hours after some instance which has previously been discussed or indicated.  For example:

> He will leave when he has finished fixing his bicycle.  He will come back after two hours

In which case, the time of his return is undefined because the time required to fix his bicycle is uncertain.  Contrast this with

> He left as soon as he fixed his bicycle.  He will come back in two hours.

Doesn't matter how long ago he left; he will return two hours from *now*.

Comment: Yes, and to add or further clarify: "after" and "later" and "before" are typically used to talk about time from a past or future time (but not the present time). "In," "from now," and "ago" are used to talk about time from now.

Comment: I don't buy this answer. "He will leave when he has finished fixing his bicycle. He will come back after two hours." could still be interpreted to mean that he will finish fixing his bicycle AND come back two hours from now. If the second sentence was "He will come back two hours after." then I'd be more inclined to agree.

Comment: "Could still" - *maybe*. I used "implies" rather than simply an absolute "means" with care, to say this is the *likely* interpretation. However, I would see your alternative as a bad interpretation unless there was extra context.  I believe my interpretation is more likely to be inferred, by more people. Thus far, the number of up votes compared to your down vote provide a very crude validation.

Comment: @talrnu Could you provide some instances of native speakers using _after_ in this sense? I for one have **never** heard a native speaker do so in my life—it is in fact one of the most frequent errors that clearly mark Chinese and Japanese speakers as such, in my experience.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I have no examples unfortunately, only anecdotal evidence and a native speaker's intuition. I think it might help if I elaborate: you could say there's an implied "that" associated with the use of *after* I provide, i.e. "He will come back two hours after [that]." This makes it absolutely clear that the two hour period begins when the bicycle repairs are finished and not right now. Without that degree of clarity, I'd be uncertain when the two hours begins, and would have to ask for a more specific indication.

Comment: In my experience, @talrnu, also as a native speaker, "after two hours" is quite common usage.  Most people seem not to find it as disconcerting as you do.

Comment: @talrnu In that construction (where _after_ comes, well, after the period stated), there is little ambiguity. But that doesn’t go for the other version, the one in the question here: “I’m just going to nip down to the shop, I’ll be back after ten minutes” just simply is not idiomatic to me. At all. Google also agrees: “I’ll be back after ten minutes” yields just _five_ hits, while “I’ll be back in ten minutes” yields _145,000_.

Comment: @itsbruce I'll concede that I require more accurate communication than most people, having a below-average tolerance for failure due to incorrect assumptions.

Comment: There is no accuracy gained in moving **after** from one end to the other.

Answer (score 3):

"He will come back in two hours" implies that he will be back in exactly (or just around) two hours. "He will come back after two hours" implies that he ill return sometime after (could be a much longer time) two hours has passed.

Answer (score 3):

> He will come back in two hours

It is 6pm. At 8pm he will be knocking on the door, though he might get back earlier.

> He will come back after two hours.

It is 6pm. The earliest he will come back until after 8:01pm, but probably later.

Comment: "though he might get back earlier." or a little later. I would not infer "within this period or less" unless **inside** or **within** had been used, rather than simple **in**.  I *do* agree that "after two hours" implies "at least two hours, *possibly* more" but wouldn't say "probably".

Comment: If I leave at 6pm saying "I'll be back in two hours" and I get back 90 minutes later, I don't think anybody will be angry saying "Hey! Yousaid two hours but this is 90 minutes!" On the other hand, if I got back after 3 hours I could justifiably be accused of being late, hence "might get back earlier". I say "probably later" than 8:01pm because if I were expecting to be back shortly after 8pm I wouldn't say "after two hours". I would more likely say "in around two hours", so to justify "after two hours" it would have to be significantly after 8pm.